# Generating a matrix to describe a two-dimensional feature

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, binary, matrix-multiplication

Let's say I have a vector A = [-1,2]; 
Each element in A is described by the actual number and sign. So each element has a 2 dimensional feature-set.

I would like to generate a matrix, in this case 2x2 where the columns correspond to the element, and rows correspond to the presence of a feature. The presence of a feature is described by 1's and 0's. So, if an element is positive, it is 1, if the element is the number 1, then the result is 1 as well. In the case above I would get:

```
                                      Element 1      Element 2
Is this a 1?                             1              0

Is this a positive number?               0              1
```

What is the smartest way to go about accomplishing this? Obviously if statements would work, but I feel that there should be a faster, much smarter way of going about this. I am coding this in matlab by the way, and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Benoit_11's solution is a fine one. Here's a similar but maybe simpler solution. You could try both and see which is faster if you care about speed.

```
features = [abs(A) == 1; A > 0];
```

this assumes A is a row vector in order to get the output in the format you specified.

Comment: good catch with `abs(A) == 1` that's the smarter way I wish I had thought of haha +1

Comment: I think this works great. I should think in logicals more often.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way using [ismember](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) for the first condition and logical operation for the 2nd condition. `ismember` outputs a logical array which you can plug into the output you need (here called `DescribeA`; and likewise when you check for values greater than 0 using the `>` operator.

```
%// Test array
A = [-1,2,1,-10,5,-3,1]

%// Initialize output
DescribeA = zeros(2,numel(A));

%// 1st condition. Check if values are 1 or -1
DescribeA(1,:) = ismember(A,1)|ismember(A,-1);

%// Check if they are > 0 
DescribeA(2,:) = A>0;
```

Output in Command Window:

```
A =

    -1     2     1   -10     5    -3     1


DescribeA =

     1     0     1     0     0     0     1
     0     1     1     0     1     0     1
```

I feel there is a smarter way for the 1st condition but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I wasnt aware of the ismember function. Interesting.